# Trying to rotate a matrix k times, but unsure where I'm going wrong

Tags: python, class, matrix, rotation

Help! So I'm trying to create a program that rotates a matrix k times, where 1 row belongs to 1 column. I am able to rotate the matrix clockwise and counterclockwise, but there is something wrong with my k_rotate method and I can't find out what it is.

Basically, no matter what value k takes, it does not repeat the method as I want to. By repeating the function, I should be able to rotate the matrix over and over again and store the final value in a matrix. I believe the way I'm storing the return value is wrong, or maybe I'm calling this incorrectly... Help please.

```
import random

#let's choose four

class matrix(object):
    def __init__(self, rows, cols):
        self.matrix, self.rows, self.cols = [], rows, cols

        #initialize matrix rows with empty values
        for i in range(rows):
            self.matrix.append([])

        #now for every col per row, append a random value
        for j in self.matrix:
            for i in range(cols):
                j.append(random.randint(0, 100))

    def __repr__(self):
        printme = ""
        for i in self.matrix:
            print('\t'.join(map(str,i)))

    def rotateclockwise(self):
        temp_cols, temp_rows = self.rows, self.cols

        # initialize the temp matrix
        temp = []
        for i in range(temp_rows):
            temp.append([None for _ in range(temp_cols)])

        # paste values into the temp matrix
        for i in range(self.rows): #go through original array's rows
            for j in range(self.cols): #go through originala array's columns
                #whatever isn't new_i is new_j
                temp_i = j #the new column consists of j values
                temp_j = temp_cols - i - 1 #new row consists of the following value
                temp[temp_i][temp_j] = self.matrix[i][j] #now set the temp array to the matrix' element

        # print it out
        #idk why __repr__ doesn't work here tho
        return temp

    def rotatecounter(self):
        #must be negative for counter clockwise rotation
        temp_cols, temp_rows = self.rows, self.cols

        # initialize the temp matrix
        temp = []
        for i in range(temp_rows):
            temp.append([None for _ in range(temp_cols)])

        # paste values into the temp matrix
        for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(self.cols):
                temp_i = temp_cols - j - 1
                temp_j = i
                temp[temp_i][temp_j] = self.matrix[i][j] #now set the temp array to the matrix' element

        return temp

    def k_rotate(self, k):
        if k == 0:
            for i in self.matrix:
                print('\t'.join(map(str,i)))
        if k < 0:
            temp = []
            for i in range(abs(k)):
                temp = self.rotatecounter()
            #set self.matrix to the matrix returned here
            for i in temp:
                print('\t'.join(map(str,i)))
        if k > 0:
            temp = []
            for i in range(k):
                temp = self.rotateclockwise()
            for i in temp:
                print('\t'.join(map(str,i)))
            #set self.matrix to the matrix returned here
```